# How to Display an image, using a reference stored in an Sql database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I'm making a mini cms where users can upload images to a sidebar of their site(a div in my master page) so far I've created the insert statement into the db and the image upload, which gets uploaded to the Images folder but I'm struggling to display images from a image reference stored in an sql database, all tutorials I've found they seem to pointing towards uploading my images to the db but I just wanted use a reference stored in the db to my image.

This is what I've got so far:

Sql BannerManagment table:

```
ImageId - Int - Primary Key
ImageRef - nvarchar(50)
Url  - nvarchar(50)(this is so users can but href on the image)
SortOrder - nvarchar(50)
Active - int
```

Insert method:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDb"].ToString();

public void insertImage(string iRef, string href, string sOrder, int a)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.BannerManagment (ImageRef,Url,SortOrder,Active)" + " VALUES(@ref,@url,@sortorder,@active)";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))


    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ref", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iRef;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@url", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = href;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@sortorder", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sOrder;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Int).Value = a;


        con.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Calling the class:

```
BannerImages image = new BannerImages();
image.insertImage(FileUpload1.FileName.ToString(), txtHref.Text, txtSort.Text, i);
```

Comment: You're storing just image's URL (so why do you need a FileUpload control?). If you keep URL only then remove file upload and query image url (to use directly into img tag src). If you want to actually store image data then...do it (convert to byte array to base64 or consider using FILE streams in SQL Server) then get it back...

Comment: So they can upload the image to the server otherwise it would show a broken link and then get the reference from the db. I'm just struggling to write the query to display it has an image. How do iget it so it's string. So I Could go <img src="{0}">,dbVarHere?

Comment: You could go like that if you store URL.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to write the query if I add the full url path in?